# Using Ramda compose, groupBy and sort in order to process an array of objects

Tags: ramda.js

I am new to **Ramda** and I am trying to achieve the following:

I have an array of objects (i.e. messages).

- I want to group the messages by counter party ID (either the sender or the recipient ID, whichever is not 1, see my `groupBy` lambda below).
- I am going to obtain an object whose keys will be the counter party IDs and values an array of the messages exchanged with that counter party.
- I then want to sort by date descending those arrays of messages.
- And finally keep the most recent message and thus obtain an array containing the most recent message exchanged with each of the counter parties.

Because I have two counter parties above, I should have an array of two messages.

Here is what I have attempted:

```
const rawMessages = [
  {
    "sender": {
      "id": 1,
      "firstName": "JuliettP"
    },
    "recipient": {
      "id": 2,
      "firstName": "Julien"
    },
    "sendDate": "2017-01-28T19:21:15.863",
    "messageRead": true,
    "text": "ssssssss"
  },
  {
    "sender": {
      "id": 3,
      "firstName": "Juliani"
    },
    "recipient": {
      "id": 1,
      "firstName": "JuliettP"
    },
    "sendDate": "2017-02-01T18:08:12.894",
    "messageRead": true,
    "text": "sss"
  },
  {
    "sender": {
      "id": 2,
      "firstName": "Julien"
    },
    "recipient": {
      "id": 1,
      "firstName": "JuliettP"
    },
    "sendDate": "2017-02-07T22:19:51.649",
    "messageRead": true,
    "text": "I love redux!!"
  },
  {
    "sender": {
      "id": 1,
      "firstName": "JuliettP"
    },
    "recipient": {
      "id": 3,
      "firstName": "Juliani"
    },
    "sendDate": "2017-03-13T20:57:52.253",
    "messageRead": false,
    "text": "hello Juliani"
  },
  {
    "sender": {
      "id": 1,
      "firstName": "JuliettP"
    },
    "recipient": {
      "id": 3,
      "firstName": "Juliani"
    },
    "sendDate": "2017-03-13T20:56:52.253",
    "messageRead": false,
    "text": "hello Julianito"
  }
];

const currentUserId = 1;
const groupBy = (m: Message) => m.sender.id !== currentUserId ? m.sender.id : m.recipient.id;
const byDate = R.descend(R.prop('sendDate'));
const sort = (value, key) => R.sort(byDate, value);
const composition = R.compose(R.map, R.head, sort, R.groupBy(groupBy));
const latestByCounterParty = composition(rawMessages);
console.log(latestByCounterParty);
```

Here is the corresponding codepen:

https://codepen.io/balteo/pen/JWOWRb

Can someone please help?

**edit**: Here is a link to the uncurried version: [here](http://ramdajs.com/repl/?v=0.23.0#?const%20rawMessages%20%3D%20%5B%7B%22messageRead%22%3A%20true%2C%20%22recipient%22%3A%20%7B%22firstName%22%3A%20%22Julien%22%2C%20%22id%22%3A%202%7D%2C%20%22sendDate%22%3A%20%222017-01-28T19%3A21%3A15.863%22%2C%20%22sender%22%3A%20%7B%22firstName%22%3A%20%22JuliettP%22%2C%20%22id%22%3A%201%7D%2C%20%22text%22%3A%20%22ssssssss%22%7D%2C%20%7B%22messageRead%22%3A%20true%2C%20%22recipient%22%3A%20%7B%22firstName%22%3A%20%22JuliettP%22%2C%20%22id%22%3A%201%7D%2C%20%22sendDate%22%3A%20%222017-02-01T18%3A08%3A12.894%22%2C%20%22sender%22%3A%20%7B%22firstName%22%3A%20%22Juliani%22%2C%20%22id%22%3A%203%7D%2C%20%22text%22%3A%20%22sss%22%7D%2C%20%7B%22messageRead%22%3A%20true%2C%20%22recipient%22%3A%20%7B%22firstName%22%3A%20%22JuliettP%22%2C%20%22id%22%3A%201%7D%2C%20%22sendDate%22%3A%20%222017-02-07T22%3A19%3A51.649%22%2C%20%22sender%22%3A%20%7B%22firstName%22%3A%20%22Julien%22%2C%20%22id%22%3A%202%7D%2C%20%22text%22%3A%20%22I%20love%20redux%21%21%22%7D%2C%20%7B%22messageRead%22%3A%20false%2C%20%22recipient%22%3A%20%7B%22firstName%22%3A%20%22Juliani%22%2C%20%22id%22%3A%203%7D%2C%20%22sendDate%22%3A%20%222017-03-13T20%3A57%3A52.253%22%2C%20%22sender%22%3A%20%7B%22firstName%22%3A%20%22JuliettP%22%2C%20%22id%22%3A%201%7D%2C%20%22text%22%3A%20%22hello%20Juliani%22%7D%2C%20%7B%22messageRead%22%3A%20false%2C%20%22recipient%22%3A%20%7B%22firstName%22%3A%20%22Juliani%22%2C%20%22id%22%3A%203%7D%2C%20%22sendDate%22%3A%20%222017-03-13T20%3A56%3A52.253%22%2C%20%22sender%22%3A%20%7B%22firstName%22%3A%20%22JuliettP%22%2C%20%22id%22%3A%201%7D%2C%20%22text%22%3A%20%22hello%20Julianito%22%7D%5D%3B%0Aconst%20currentUserId%20%3D%201%3B%0A%0Aconst%20currentMessagesForId%20%3D%20%28id%2C%20msgs%29%20%3D%3E%0A%20%20R.pipe%28%0A%20%20%20%20R.groupBy%28m%20%3D%3E%20m.sender.id%20%21%3D%3D%20id%20%3F%20m.sender.id%20%3A%20m.recipient.id%29%2C%0A%20%20%20%20R.map%28R.sort%28R.descend%28R.prop%28%27sendDate%27%29%29%29%29%2C%0A%20%20%20%20R.map%28R.head%29%2C%20%0A%20%20%20%20R.values%0A%20%20%29%28msgs%29%3B%0A%0AcurrentMessagesForId%28currentUserId%2C%20rawMessages%29%3B%0A). The behavior is identical without the currying. See my comment below with my question as to the necessity of currying.

Comment: Thanks a lot to both of you!! If I could have accepted both answers I would have done so. I might have more questions regarding the provided answers. I will post here accordingly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While I think the [solution from Scott Christopher](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42845735/1243641) is fine, there are two more steps that I might take with it myself.

Noting that one of the [important rules](https://github.com/fantasyland/fantasy-land#functor) about map is that

```
map(compose(f, g)) ≍ compose(map(f), map(g))
```

when we're already inside a composition pipeline, we can choose to unnest this step:

```
R.map(R.compose(R.head, R.sort(R.descend(R.prop('sendDate'))))),
```

and turn the overall solution into

```
const currentMessagesForId = R.curry((id, msgs) =>
  R.compose(
    R.values,
    R.map(R.head), 
    R.map(R.sort(R.descend(R.prop('sendDate')))),
    R.groupBy(m => m.sender.id !== id ? m.sender.id : m.recipient.id)
  )(msgs)
)
```

Doing this, is, of course, a matter of taste.  But I find it cleaner.  The next step is also a matter of taste.  I choose to use `compose` for things that can be listed on a single line, and hence make some obvious connection between the formats `compose(f, g, h)(x)` and `f(g(h(x)))`.  If it spans multiple lines, I prefer to use `pipe`, which behaves the same way, but runs it's functions from first to last.  So I would change this a bit further to look like this:

```
const currentMessagesForId = R.curry((id, msgs) =>
  R.pipe(
    R.groupBy(m => m.sender.id !== id ? m.sender.id : m.recipient.id),
    R.map(R.sort(R.descend(R.prop('sendDate')))),
    R.map(R.head), 
    R.values
  )(msgs)
)
```

I find this top-down reading easier than the bottom up needed with longer `compose` versions.

But, as I said, these are matters of taste.

You can see these examples on the **[Ramda REPL](http://ramdajs.com/repl/?v=0.23.0#?const%20rawMessages%20%3D%20%5B%7B%22messageRead%22%3A%20true%2C%20%22recipient%22%3A%20%7B%22firstName%22%3A%20%22Julien%22%2C%20%22id%22%3A%202%7D%2C%20%22sendDate%22%3A%20%222017-01-28T19%3A21%3A15.863%22%2C%20%22sender%22%3A%20%7B%22firstName%22%3A%20%22JuliettP%22%2C%20%22id%22%3A%201%7D%2C%20%22text%22%3A%20%22ssssssss%22%7D%2C%20%7B%22messageRead%22%3A%20true%2C%20%22recipient%22%3A%20%7B%22firstName%22%3A%20%22JuliettP%22%2C%20%22id%22%3A%201%7D%2C%20%22sendDate%22%3A%20%222017-02-01T18%3A08%3A12.894%22%2C%20%22sender%22%3A%20%7B%22firstName%22%3A%20%22Juliani%22%2C%20%22id%22%3A%203%7D%2C%20%22text%22%3A%20%22sss%22%7D%2C%20%7B%22messageRead%22%3A%20true%2C%20%22recipient%22%3A%20%7B%22firstName%22%3A%20%22JuliettP%22%2C%20%22id%22%3A%201%7D%2C%20%22sendDate%22%3A%20%222017-02-07T22%3A19%3A51.649%22%2C%20%22sender%22%3A%20%7B%22firstName%22%3A%20%22Julien%22%2C%20%22id%22%3A%202%7D%2C%20%22text%22%3A%20%22I%20love%20redux%21%21%22%7D%2C%20%7B%22messageRead%22%3A%20false%2C%20%22recipient%22%3A%20%7B%22firstName%22%3A%20%22Juliani%22%2C%20%22id%22%3A%203%7D%2C%20%22sendDate%22%3A%20%222017-03-13T20%3A57%3A52.253%22%2C%20%22sender%22%3A%20%7B%22firstName%22%3A%20%22JuliettP%22%2C%20%22id%22%3A%201%7D%2C%20%22text%22%3A%20%22hello%20Juliani%22%7D%2C%20%7B%22messageRead%22%3A%20false%2C%20%22recipient%22%3A%20%7B%22firstName%22%3A%20%22Juliani%22%2C%20%22id%22%3A%203%7D%2C%20%22sendDate%22%3A%20%222017-03-13T20%3A56%3A52.253%22%2C%20%22sender%22%3A%20%7B%22firstName%22%3A%20%22JuliettP%22%2C%20%22id%22%3A%201%7D%2C%20%22text%22%3A%20%22hello%20Julianito%22%7D%5D%3B%0Aconst%20currentUserId%20%3D%201%3B%0A%0A%2F%2A%0Aconst%20currentMessagesForId%20%3D%20R.curry%28%28id%2C%20msgs%29%20%3D%3E%0A%20%20R.compose%28%0A%20%20%20%20R.values%2C%0A%20%20%20%20R.map%28R.compose%28R.head%2C%20R.sort%28R.descend%28R.prop%28%27sendDate%27%29%29%29%29%29%2C%0A%20%20%20%20R.groupBy%28m%20%3D%3E%20m.sender.id%20%21%3D%3D%20id%20%3F%20m.sender.id%20%3A%20m.recipient.id%29%0A%20%20%29%28msgs%29%29%0A%0AcurrentMessagesForId%28currentUserId%2C%20rawMessages%29%0A%2A%2F%0A%2F%2A%0Aconst%20currentMessagesForId%20%3D%20R.curry%28%28id%2C%20msgs%29%20%3D%3E%0A%20%20R.compose%28%0A%20%20%20%20R.values%2C%0A%20%20%20%20R.map%28R.head%29%2C%20%0A%20%20%20%20R.map%28R.sort%28R.descend%28R.prop%28%27sendDate%27%29%29%29%29%2C%0A%20%20%20%20R.groupBy%28m%20%3D%3E%20m.sender.id%20%21%3D%3D%20id%20%3F%20m.sender.id%20%3A%20m.recipient.id%29%0A%20%20%29%28msgs%29%0A%29%0A%0AcurrentMessagesForId%28currentUserId%2C%20rawMessages%29%0A%2A%2F%0A%0Aconst%20currentMessagesForId%20%3D%20R.curry%28%28id%2C%20msgs%29%20%3D%3E%0A%20%20R.pipe%28%0A%20%20%20%20R.groupBy%28m%20%3D%3E%20m.sender.id%20%21%3D%3D%20id%20%3F%20m.sender.id%20%3A%20m.recipient.id%29%2C%0A%20%20%20%20R.map%28R.sort%28R.descend%28R.prop%28%27sendDate%27%29%29%29%29%2C%0A%20%20%20%20R.map%28R.head%29%2C%20%0A%20%20%20%20R.values%0A%20%20%29%28msgs%29%0A%29%0A%0AcurrentMessagesForId%28currentUserId%2C%20rawMessages%29%0A)**.

Comment: There one last thing I don't get: why did you both of you use `R.curry`? I tried removing the currying part and the result is the same (link provided in my edit). Why is currying required here?

Comment: Ramda's `curry` adds some flexibility in how you call the function.  It's not necessary, and if you know you always want to call it as `currentMessagesForId(id, msgs)`, then its not helpful at all.  But when it's curried, you can create a new function by partially applying it.  So `const msgsForMe = currentMessagesForId(myId);` and then later use `msgsForMe(msgs)`.  You can read more about currying in **[an old article of mine](http://fr.umio.us/favoring-curry/)**.

Answer (score 2):

Your example was close to what you wanted, though you need just needed to move the composition of `head` and `sort` to the function argument given to `map` and then call `values` on the final result to convert the object to an array of values.

```
const currentMessagesForId = R.curry((id, msgs) =>
  R.compose(
    R.values,
    R.map(R.compose(R.head, R.sort(R.descend(R.prop('sendDate'))))),
    R.groupBy(m => m.sender.id !== id ? m.sender.id : m.recipient.id)
  )(msgs))

currentMessagesForId(currentUserId, rawMessages)
```